Angular ReadOnly signals being affected? e.g. by array.pop
Why is that when in a signal store (in a service), when I do
Service
  protected static readonly removedAllowances: WritableSignal<(ContractAllowanceDTO)[]> = signal<(ContractAllowanceDTO})[]>([]);

  /* getters */
  public getRemovedllowances() {
    return computed(() => ContractService.removedAllowances())
  }

Component
In the component class
  protected readonly removedAllowances = this.contractService.getRemovedAllowances();

  let removedAllowances: any[];
  removedAllowances = this.removedAllowances();

  removedAllowances.pop();
  console.log('allowance', this.contractService.getRemovedAllowances()())

It's console logging the result as if the variable in the service, ContractService.removedAllowances(), has also been popped. I thought signals were read only? Why should removedAllowances.pop() at all affect ContractService.removedAllowances()?

Primitive types -> Number, String, Boolean, Undefined, Null and Symbol
Signal fires when the actual value changes ( 1 != 2 -> change fires )
Non-Primitive Types -> Object, Array, etc.
Are stored as references in memory.
Signal fires when the memory reference changes ( memref != memref2 change fires )
Also when you change a nested property of a non primitive type, the reference does not change!

SO you are modifying the data inside the array, but not the actual reference, so the changes are reflecting in all places having the same reference, to solve this, create a deep clone! (new reference created)
  protected readonly removedAllowances = this.contractService.getRemovedAllowances();

  let removedAllowances: any[];
  removedAllowances = structuredClone(this.removedAllowances()); //<- changed here!

  removedAllowances.pop();
  console.log('allowance', this.contractService.getRemovedAllowances()())


I used the spread operator in the getter [... array] which solved things
